# Нужно ли заключать в кавычки термин, который пишется после слова "называется"?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Нужно ли заключать в кавычки термин,который стоит в форме творительного падежа и пишется после слова"называется"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В таком случае кавычки не ставятся: ***называется префиксом, называется симплокой.*** Глагол НАЗЫВАЕТСЯ уже готовит читателя к восприятию термина, нового или необычного слова.

Кавычки не ставятся и после слов "так называемый": 
+ ***Не заключаются в кавычки слова, следующие за словосочетанием так называемый. Исключение составляют случаи, когда эти слова употреблены в необычном или ироническом значении.***   [Здесь](http://writercenter.ru/blog/grammar/21913.html)